# Does Laravel take care of the AWS SES 50 email address limit?

Tags: laravel, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

AWS SES guide:

> Maximum number of recipients per message:
>
> 50 recipients per message. A recipient is any "To", "CC", or "BCC"
>   address.

Source: [AWS SES Developer Guides](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/limits.html)

I'm currently using the following function:

```
Mail::send(['html' => 'emails.systemmail'],['mail' => $mail],
           function($message) use ($emails){
              $message->to($emails);
              $message->subject('email subject');
           });
```

Question: if the `$emails` array has more than 50 email addresses, what happens?

- Does Laravel automatically send it in batches limited by 50?
- Does SES automatically send it in batches limited by 50?
- Are only the first 50 sent?
- Are no emails sent and the SES server returns an error?

Do I need to array split and send it in batches of maximum 50 myself?

Bonus:

- Is there any common/standard workaround?
- What if there are 30 "To:" addresses and 30 "CC:" addresses?

Comment: Interesting question. I suspect it'll error out with an API error of some sort. In most cases where you're emailing large numbers of people you want to hide the recipients list, which means sending one-by-one anyways. What's your use case?

Comment: actually i put them into "bcc", but thought it might keep the question simple  set it as "to"

Comment: contact AWS directly to extend the SES limits, no need struggling with this

Comment: ok, will try and contact them. Thank you for the idea.

Comment: @BMW I'm not sure this particular limit is liftable.